# Listen for additional requests on the same stream (TCPClient/SSLStream)?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, sslstream

So I have a client server model based off of using a TCPClient's stream and turning it into an SSLStream for security purposes, but each time the client wants to send something new to the server, it opens a new TCP connection to the server as the server ends the connection at the end. How would I go about listening for additional requests from the same stream? Not sure how and that's why I'm killing the stream at the end. Sorry if it's confusing, I can revise if not understandable. Thanks!

```
public void ServerListen()
{
TCPListener Server = new TCPListener(IPAddress.Any, 8001);
while (true)
{
Server.Start();
TCPClient TempClient = Server.AcceptTCPClient();
HandleRequest NewRequest = new HandleRequest(TempClient); // Send to a data handler class and open a separate thread to allow for additional clients to connect
}
}


public class HandleRequest
{

TCPClient WorkingClient;
public HandleRequest(TCPClient TempClient)
{
WorkingClient = TempClient;
(new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork))).Start();
}

public static void DoWork()
{
// Do Something Here With Data From Client
ProvideResponse(SomeData);
}

public static void ProvideResponse(object Data)
{
SSLStream SecureStream = new SSLStream(WorkingClient, false); // Kill inner stream after creating a secure connection
SecureStream.AuthenticateAsServer(MyCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
XmlSerializer XS = new XMLSerializer(typeof(someclass));
someclass TempObject = new someclass(){ InnerData = Data};
if (SecureStream.CanWrite)
{
XS.Serialize(SecureStream, TempObject);
}
SecureStream.Close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SslStream` simply wraps around another `Stream`. If you call `AuthenticateAsServer()` the other side should `AuthenticateAsClient()` and from that point on you can communicate over SSL. If either side fails to call this method, the `SslStream` will throw an exception.

If you close an `SslStream` constructed with the `leaveInnerStreamOpen` parameter set to `true`, you can then communicate directly over the underlying stream as if there never was an `SslStream` (and you can even send and receive directly to/from the underlying stream *while* the `SslStream` is still open).

In a typical scenario like HTTPS, client and server would enable SSL as soon as the connection is established, and continue using that for the duration of the connection. There's nothing stopping you though from closing the `SslStream` on both sides after a request/response, and recreating one for the next message - you'd just have to keep the "ssl state" synchronized between client and server.

As for your comment:

Once a TCP connection is established, you can send and receive data for as long as both sides stay connected. For example:

```
TcpClient client = TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
while (true)
{
    int bytes = stream.Read(...);
    if (bytes == 0) 
    {
        // other side has disconnected
        stream.Close();
        break;
    }

    // add incoming data to buffer, process messages
    ...
}
```

It's like talking to someone by writing text on a piece of paper you show to one another - you simply continue writing on the same piece of paper, and the other side can read while you write.

If you close the `TcpClient` after a request/response and open a new one using `TcpListener.AcceptXxx()`, you're throwing away each piece of paper after every message.

If I were you I'd play with these concepts (using the `NetworkStream` class) *without* the `SslStream` wrapper, until you feel you're doing the right thing. The `SslStream` layer can be added without any significant changes to code that uses `NetworkStream`.

Comment: I actually find that very helpful. So once I set the SSLStream and authenticate, leave the inner stream open,  the TCPClient would then be using the underlying SSL connection? If that's the case, how would i listen for additional requests from the TCPClient once the "ProvideResponse" method is complete?

Comment: You'd use `NetworkStream stream = myTCPClient.GetStream()`, and both communicate via that stream unencrypted, and create the `SslStream` from it.

Comment: Sorry maybe I misspoke. I can create the SSLStream (See provide response) but once I do that, and complete the work I need to (send the response), how do I accept further requests via the TCPClient? Would it be something like the TCPListener `While (WorkingClient.Connect) { // do work  }`?

Comment: Leaves me some questions regarding the use of the XMLSerializer but that could be an entirely different question and I think you've appropriately answered the question I actually asked or at least given me some good direction and insight. Much appreciated.